# Sorting on nested fields containing null values in elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch

I am trying to sort on nested field in elasticsearch, but it is always showing docs with null valued nested field at the top of the sorted list while sorting in ascending order. I want to sort (in ascending as well as descending order) and want the null valued nested field docs to appear at the end of the sorted list.

This is the sorting query I am using :

```
{
  "query": {
    "match_all": {}
  },
  "sort": {
    "_script": {
      "type": "string",
      "order": "asc",
      "script": {
        "lang": "painless",
        "source": "def val=params['_source'].tags; if(val==null){return '';}else{return params['_source'].tags} "
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Below is the mapping I have applied related to the nested 'tags' field:

```
"tags": {
            "type": "nested",
            "properties": {
              "tag": {
                "type": "text",
                "fields": {
                  "keyword": {
                    "type": "keyword",
                    "ignore_above": 256
                  }
                },
                "analyzer": "index_analyzer",
                "search_analyzer": "search_analyzer"
              }
            }
          }
```

Sample payload:

```
"tags": [
  {
    "tag": "check"
  },
  {
    "tag": "production"
  },
  {
    "tag": "test"
  }
]
```

Comment: Sorry i have no time for a real answer but your use case is just a standard nested sort with the missing: "_last" property. Check the documentation here https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/7.3/search-request-body.html#_missing_values_4

Comment: I tried this, but it gives a null pointer exception whenever I try to sort a document in which the tags field is missing.

Comment: I think you dont understand :p you dont need a custom script to do that. I will make  a real answer in a minute :)

Answer (score 3):

Since tags is a nested property, you need to apply a [nested sort](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/6.3/search-request-sort.html#nested-sorting) on it, and to make document without tags last in the results list you only add to use the [`missing` property](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/6.3/search-request-sort.html#_missing_values).

**nb:** We sort in the subfield keyword of the tags since sorting key need to be not analyzed.

Here the example query :

```
{
    "query": {
        "match_all": {}
    },
    "sort": [
        {
            "tags.tag.keyword": {
                "order": "asc",
                "missing": "_last",
                "nested": {
                    "path": "tags"
                }
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

Since you are sorting on multi values text field I recommend you to check this sort documentation section about [sorting modes](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/6.3/search-request-sort.html#_sort_mode_option) for a better understanding of elasticsearch behavior in such case.

Hope it helps!